# Custom Conversion from Java Object to JSON Object

Tags: java, json, hibernate, gson

I have the following code

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(criteria.list()); // list is passed by Hibernate
```

The result would be something like this:

```
{creationTime:0, enabled:true, id:1, loginDuration:0, online:false, userName:someone}
```

I would like to add new attribute (DT_RowId which has the same value as id) within the JSON response. The end result should be like this:

```
{creationTime:0, enabled:true, id:1, loginDuration:0, online:false, userName:someone, DT_RowId=1}
```

**UPDATED**

I created a field with @Transient annotation on the entity in order to solve this issue.

```
    ...
    @Transient
    private long DT_RowId;

    public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
            this.DT_RowId=id;
        }
    ...
```

However the setId function was never been called. Can someone enlighten me on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GSON won't call your getters and setters. It accesses member vars directly via reflection. To accomplish what you are trying to do, you will need to use a GSON custom serializer/deserializer. [The GSON docs on custom serializers/deserializers](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization) provide some examples for how to do this.

Here is a working example with a passing JUnit test that demonstrates how to do it:

### Entity.java

```
public class Entity {
    protected long creationTime;
    protected boolean enabled;
    protected long id;
    protected long loginDuration;
    protected boolean online;
    protected String userName;
    protected long DT_RowId;
}
```

### EntityJsonSerializer.java

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import com.google.gson.*;

public class EntityJsonSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Entity> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Entity entity, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
       entity.DT_RowId = entity.id;
       Gson gson = new Gson();
       return gson.toJsonTree(entity);
    }
}
```

### JSONTest.java

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.google.gson.*;

public class JSONTest {
    @Test
    public final void testSerializeWithDTRowId() {
        Entity entity = new Entity();
        entity.creationTime = 0;
        entity.enabled = true;
        entity.id = 1;
        entity.loginDuration = 0;
        entity.online = false;
        entity.userName = "someone";

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Entity.class, new EntityJsonSerializer());
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        String json = gson.toJson(entity);
        String expectedJson = "{\"creationTime\":0,\"enabled\":true,\"id\":1,\"loginDuration\":0,\"online\":false,\"userName\":\"someone\",\"DT_RowId\":1}";
        assertEquals(expectedJson, json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample code. I was reading the documentation and trying to come up with the solution. Is it possible to make it generic ?

Comment: @abiieez: You're welcome. I realized, after looking at the doc link that I posted, that it really wasn't that obvious how to make this work. And so I did some experimentation and this is what I came up with that actually worked. I imagine it can be improved upon. I suggest posting a new question on how best to make the solution generic for your needs.